# Removing decimals in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, select, decimal

My question is rather short but I have a issue finding a answer. But I have a select in SQL that has the following search:

```
Max(CashTrans.Costprice)
```

In my result in SQL I get the following

```
-1180,00
-1377,502
-0,40
-460,00
-100,00
-100,00
-100,00
-100,00
-100,00
```

What is the most effective and easiest way removing "," and all decimals after so the result would end up with

```
-1180
-1377
-0
-460
-100
-100
-100
-100
-100
```

Thanks and have a good day!

Comment: Please use the ROUND() function in SQL as below:

**SELECT ROUND(column_name,0) FROM your_table**.
You may also explore other options of rounding up/down as per your requirements using CEILING or FLOOR functions.

Comment: @Ankush, `round` doesn't remove decimals, it just rounds them off, you'll still have decimals.

Comment: @HoneyBadger - Thanks for your input. Sorry that I missed the most important point in the question. 
Edit - **SELECT CAST(ROUND(column_name,0) AS int) FROM your_table**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
CONVERT(INT, Max(CashTrans.Costprice))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(columnname AS INT) AS columnname from tablename
```

or

```
Select 
SUBSTRING(a,0,CHARINDEX(',',a)) from #Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Max(cast(CashTrans.Costprice as int))
from your_table
...
```

Answer (score 0):

IF we are not sure of data types and instead of dealing with conversion errors

```
Select 
SUBSTRING(ID,0,CHARINDEX(',',ID)) from Table
```